# Mysql WHERE clause not working?

Tags: mysql

I've looked at a bunch of articles on here but I can't find quite what I'm looking for

```
SELECT SUM(adult) as adult_sold_1 WHERE showtime = '1'From tickets
```

Everything here works but when I try to use WHERE the entire thing stops working...

What's wrong with this?

EDIt:

Also is there a way to do multiple at once??

Like

```
SELECT SUM(adult) as adult_sold_1 From tickets WHERE showtime = '1'
```

then the same thing with student in spot of adult?

Comment: Where are you selecting this `FROM`?

Comment: SELECT SUM(adult) as adult_sold_1 WHERE showtime = '1'  FROM tickets"

Comment: See the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html - as per your edit, the `FROM` is in the wrong place. The manual will tell you where to put it.

Comment: What is the `showtime` column type?

Comment: SELECT SUM(adult) as adult_sold_1 WHERE showtime = '1' FROM tickets" No.. try mine

Comment: Correct is select sum(adult) as adult_sold_1 from tickets where showtime='1';

Comment: just wondering, you followed bunch of articles and nowhere you found correct syntax ????

Comment: @developer it is int

Comment: SELECT SUM(adult) as adult_sold_1 From tickets WHERE showtime = '1' . Where have you find that that FROM will be in after the WHERE clause?

Comment: do not use single quote if the field is `int` type, Actually, i think both will accept.

Comment: 'Also is there a way to do multiple at once??' what to be multiplied, specify your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT` query should be like:

```
SELECT `field_name` FROM `table_name`
```

On having WHERE clause:

```
SELECT `field_name` FROM `table_name` WHERE `field_name` = 'some_value'
```

In your query, `FROM` is not written & and is not properly placed.  It should be like:

```
SELECT SUM(`adult`) as adult_sold_1 FROM `tickets` WHERE `showtime` = '1'
```

**SUM() Syntax:**

```
SELECT SUM(`column_name`) FROM `table_name` WHERE condition;
```

**Multiple SUM()** Example:

Ex 1:-

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN `item` = 'ABC' THEN `price` END) as ABC_price,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `item` = 'XYZ' THEN `price` END) as XYZ_price
FROM `item_table`
```

Ex 2:-

```
SELECT SUM(`price`) as total_price, SUM(`quantity`) as total_quantity FROM `item_table`
```

Answer (score 4):

You have no FROM (table) which is causing you to have an error

SELECT SUM(adult) as adult_sold_1 FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE showtime = '1'

Comment: Who has down vote it and why? What is the wrong here..?               
SELECT SUM(adult) as adult_sold_1 From tickets WHERE showtime = '1' .     This is obviously working..?

Comment: If someone down vote any right answer and he needs to show the proper reason for that, I think..

Comment: Yeah, I think there are a lot of people that just do it out of spite or to be mean

Comment: Welcome @Kingsley

Comment: This answered it for me. thank you so much! ( I don't know why I got 4 dislikes on this though... ouch? )

Comment: No worries buddy, don't forget to upvote, if you can :)

Comment: Yeah, I know right it's annoying when you are a new person and you are asking legitimate questions to get better.Keep trying and even though you get set back, keep in there

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(adult) as adult_sold_1 
From tickets
WHERE `showtime` = 1
```

if your showtime is integer I think it doesn't need ' '
if your showtime is string use `LIKE` instead of `=`

```
WHERE `showtime` like '1'
```